# How much social media control can your employer exert over you?

Tags: human-rights, switzerland, european-court-of-human-rights

Can a swiss employer force the employee to change the display picture and full name of your personal linkedin profile?

Comment: The answer is that it depends. If you are employed by Microsoft and have the user name "Microsoft Sucks" or a photograph of you urinating on an X-Box, quite probably yes. They may have some control under your employment contract (which at minimum will probably prohibit you defaming the company or damaging its business) and commercial confidentiality/trade secret/financial reporting/etc laws (which may prevent you revealing certain information). They probably can't tell you to change your name if it's genuinely your name, unless there is a particularly good reason.

Comment: @StuartF While I agree, I doubt that MS will hire you based on that profile.

Comment: @PMF That's why you only change your profile picture *after* you have been hired.

Comment: @PeterM Lool. Still dubious to use a defamatory profile picture for your current employer. Something is wrong if you have to do that.

Comment: @PMF I'm not suggesting that is a good idea.  Just that people can do things after they have been hired.

Answer (score -1):

If your display picture or your user name have some clear reference to your employer then yes your employer may have a say in it. See stuart F's comment for examples, even if the examples are similar but positive about the employer the same would apply.

In all other cases it is none of your employers business what you do in your personal life and on social media (as long as it does not relate directly to your employer).

Comment: Is this answer informed by some actual law you could point to, or is it just a guess?

Comment: This is not entirely true, sexist, homophobic, racist or any other inflammatory language on social media can be totally unrelated to your employer and still get you fired.

Comment: In the US employment is usually “at will” and an employer can fire you for, as often said, how you comb your hair. Any reason or no reason as long as it is not a violation of anti-discrimination laws.